# All devices lost connection while a particular device connects

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

We have a office for ~50 devices. Our network setup is like this (top to down):

- DSL model from ISP
- Router
- Wi-Fi AP (connects to router, used like a switch)

Our network setup will sometimes came into a stall and the only way is to reboot the router. But this doesn't happen often.

Recently, we have a new colleague and has a device that would reliably "reproduce" this just by connecting to our wireless network.

I have captured the entire events with Wireshark, and looks like every device is asking for router's ARP address, but never get a response back.

It's not a ARP spoofing attack since there's no ARP response with spoofed MACs.

Is there anything that's suggested to look for?